# Compare disks for missing files with differing directory structure

Tags: backup, deduplication

Apologies for the length of this post, I've tried to keep it short as possible.

I'm looking for a tool / method which, given two paths, would show which files are not present in one of the paths. The caveat is that the organisation of the directories is not the same. Identical files might exist at different depths and in differently named directories in each of the 2 'given paths'. AFAIK diff, rsync, meld, freefilesync, and the duplicate finders don't do this (happy to be put right on that).

I've searched a fair bit and can't find anything that is designed to do this. Programs like rmlint could be leveraged to do it with additional work to post process the output but I am hoping theres a cleaner way to do it. Since there are a lot of files (something like 5 million, probably 1.5 million unique) taking about 6TB a tool designed to do it reasonably efficiently would be good to find.

A basic match based on name and size is adequate, since I would be copying unique files to the final destination and will use a different technique later to check the directories that are destined for deletion. In other words, I'm assembling a final backup disk and going through old disks to check they contain nothing thats not already in the main backup, before recycling those old disks for offline copies of the backup etc.

The nature of the duplication is largely multiple copies of things like home directories, taken a few months apart and stored in a completely logic free way (25 years or so of that from several machines at any one time). So maybe a copy one time stored on one disk and then another date a different disk before going back to the original disk for the next etc. I am manually identifying these almost-duplicates but once I have them I need to check inside them, and frequently it seems I rearranged data in these home directories between backups.

Any recommendations of software or failing that suggestions of how to approach it would be very welcome. Currently I'm wondering about writing something myself with a sqlite backend but the problem with that is bugginess etc, if theres more robust products or methods known in the art I would prefer to go down that route.

Comment: How do you identify a file? Path and name? Just name? Contents? Each one of the above requires different strategies. Also relevant is the number (sizes) of the files, and if you expect many differences or just a few. If there are few differences, and file names and paths don't change (too much), the first stop is the Unix program `diff`.

Comment: If your aim is to _archive_ all your data, deduplicating backup software (e.g. [Borg](https://www.borgbackup.org/)) may be of help. It will store the actual data only once, while retaining all the original file paths (which is something you seemingly don't want, but is possibly not a huge price to pay).

Comment: Diff will no doubt come into it at some point but the problem is diff -r compares subdirectories and their structure - if the structure has changed, IE been reorganised, it will see the two copies (on each side of the comparison) as unique. Some other tool is required to sort this issue out before diff can be used (if required) for a more in depth check of the two files identified as potential duplicates. BTW re 'How do you identify a file', as I said a match based on size and name.

Comment: Re Borg - in my case since I am properly sorting out this mess, its not suitable. I am putting much of the hard work in manually by amalgamating partial duplicates of directory trees because I can't see how this can be automated, decisions need to be taken, but a tool to more quickly show me which areas I need to look at as I work through the problem directories is what I am after.

Comment: @pete did you ever come up with a solution. I am going through the EXACT same scenario... many drives over years, with different hierarchies. My "quick" solution was to get a 16TB drive and create a new library in LightRoom (since all my files are photos or video), and then import from each drive into the new library on larger drive and turn on "do not import suspected duplicates"... but I don't fully trust their logic (since they don't share).

Comment: @mondo - nope I didn't. I started writing something - sort of collection of scripts. Decided IIRC to use mysql too, but other things took over and its gone fallow at the mo. I will get back to it at some point though because I didn't find anything that suited me perfectly - the DB aspect was useful because it meant I could add disks that I 'found' in later years and scan them for new files that didn't exist. The source disks are still just waiting.